# I am trying to push a JSON values one by one into localstorage but i am getting duplicate and undefined values

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to push a JSON values one by one into localstorage but i am getting duplicate and undefined values

```
this.offlineArray.push(postData[0]);

let checkLocData = localStorage.getItem("dataremove");

if(!checkLocData) {
    localStorage.setItem("dataremove",JSON.stringfy(this.offlineArray));
    this.offlineArray = [];
 } else {
    let locarray = JSON.parse(checkLocData);
    this.offlineArray.push(locarray[0]);
    localStorage.setItem("dataremove", JSON.stringify(this.offlineArray))
    this.offlineArray = [];
 }
```